# In firefox browser of mac osx Document.activeelement returns body instead of button element on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, firefox, browser

On my javascript I am using document.activeelement to get the active element but for the button click it is giving me body instead of button in firefox browser of Mac OSX Yosemite. In windows it works fine.

Can any one please help on how to get the active element as button .

Sample code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function MainElement(){
    ActiveElement();}
    function ActiveElement()
    {
    var obj;

    obj=(window.event)?((event.target)?event.target:(event.srcElement)?event.srcElement:null):document.activeElement;

   alert(obj); // returns body element
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button onclick="MainElement()"></button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Within the `click` event => `event.target` and also, post your code.

Comment: I have tried event.target also but that doesn't work.

Comment: @user3510028 Explain doesn't work?! And post relevant code you are using... FYI, FF doesn't use global event model, you need to pass it explecitely as param to handler method, but without seeing any of your relevant code, how can we help you more???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML as:

```
<button onclick="MainElement(event)">Button</button>
```

And JavaScript as:

```
function MainElement(event) {
    ActiveElement(event);
}
function ActiveElement(event) {

    event = event || window.event
    alert (event.target); //The button HTMLElement
    alert (event.target.tagName); //BUTTON
}
```

Some notes:

- In IE, the event object is accessed completely through the explicit object `window.event`.
- In Firefox, the event object is accessed by *passing* an event parameter into the event handler function in question.

Comment: But I cant pass any parameter in the function. Is there other way without passing the parameter?

Comment: I have changed my code. As I need to call one function from the another function the above answer will not be applicable.

Comment: It _is_ applicable as per your question before the edits you've made! Even with the edits, all you need to do is keep passing the event object. See my edits.

Comment: instead of passing event is there any other way?

Comment: May be, but, why can't you pass the event object?

Comment: Because to add a parameter, again we don't want to change the whole website.